# Is it right to put intent inside a Runnable thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, runnable

In my app I use Room library for read/write values. In one activity I am reading a value from my SQLite db and I need to pass that value to next activity. Just because we cannot read values in main thread I am using a different thread. When I tried to put those values to `intent.putExtra` outside the thread it gives me `Nullpointerexception`. But if I put my `intent` within the thread everything seem to be ok. I wanna know whether is it ok to put my intent within the thread? Is this the correct method? Do I need to use AsyncTask?

```
    Runnable r = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            List<Vehicle> list = dDb.vehicleDao().getAll();
            for (Vehicle s : list) {
                vehicleNumber = s.getVehicleNo();
                vehicleDescrp = s.getDescription();
            }

            // Session manager
            session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

            // Check if user is already logged in or not
            if (session.isLoggedIn()) {

                // Launch main activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("VEHICLEID", vehicleNumber);
                intent.putExtra("VEHICLEDS", vehicleDescrp);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

            }
        }
    };

    Thread newThread= new Thread(r);
    newThread.start();
```

Comment: Take advantage of an **AsyncTask** instead, it's perfect for the job. Run your algorithm in **doInBackground(...){ //run in background }** and build your intent in it's **onPostExecute(..){ // run on main thread }** method.

Comment: ok i will try. thank you

Comment: @JoeyDalu AsyncTask doesnt have big advantage with simple Thread. After all AsyncTask is just wrapper over Thread. Better to use RxJava or Coroutines.

Comment: @DEADMC true, but AsyncTask is advisable for short running tasks and increases simplicity

Answer (score 2):

That will not work because you cannot do things like opening `Actvity` outside of the `Main Thread`.

If you really need it you have to wrap it with

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     void run() {
         // Do stuff…
     }
});
```

So in ur case it will look like

```
Runnable r = new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        List<Vehicle> list = dDb.vehicleDao().getAll();
        for (Vehicle s : list) {
            vehicleNumber = s.getVehicleNo();
            vehicleDescrp = s.getDescription();
        }

        // Session manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        // Check if user is already logged in or not
        if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
           LoginActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
           void run() {
                // Launch main activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("VEHICLEID", vehicleNumber);
                intent.putExtra("VEHICLEDS", vehicleDescrp);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
        }
    };

Thread newThread= new Thread(r);
newThread.start();
```